# html: 3 columns, in center mus be fixed width

Tags: html, css

i need have 3 columns in one row. Column in center is fixed width, but left and right column must be fluid. Also I need open this page with Android and IE8. So it should works and with old browser.

What i need:
[image]

My try, but unsuccessful:

```
.left {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: -50%;
    height: 230px;
    background: url('left.png') no-repeat right top;
}
.center {
    float: left;
    margin-left: -62px;
    background: #FDE95E;
    width:123px;
    height:123px;
    background: url('center.png');
}
.right {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    height:230px;
    background: url('right.png') no-repeat left top;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="left"><br></div>
<div class="center"><br></div>
<div class="right"><br></div>
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
```

Comment: will answer with js work for you?

Comment: renleedr> I need use only CSS and HTML

Comment: then using calc() is best way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

css

```
.left {
    background: red;
    float: left;
    height: 500px;
    width: calc(50% - 50px);

}
.center {
    background: gray;
    height: 500px;
    width: 100px;
    margin: auto;
}
.right {
    background: red;
    float: right;
    height: 500px;
    width: calc(50% - 50px);
}
```

html

```
<div class="left">Left</div>
<div class="right">Right</div>
<div class="center">Center</div>
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/usb9sbje/

Comment: Not all browsers support CSS `calc()`.  There are better ways to do this.

Comment: calc is supported in all modern browsers. There are many ways to get this result, I think this is the most cleanest. Feel free to share your way.

Comment: True, some mobile browsers don't support this though.  Clever solution though! +1

Comment: Alvarez> Thanks, but i need this page open with Android and IE8, so this not works for me.

Answer (score 0):

[`flexbox`](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) ([caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox)) fixes this with ease if you don't want to use `float`.

What you need is a wrapper with `display:flex;`, set `#center` to a desired width and then your sides 50% width minus the width of the `#center`.

```css
html, body {
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
}

#wrapper {
    display:flex; /* Required. */
    height:100%;
}

#left, #right {
    background:blue;
    height:100%;
    width:calc(50% - 61px); /* 61 equals width of your #center divided by two. – Required. */
}

#center {
    width:122px;  /* Required. */
}
```

```html
<div id='wrapper'>
    <div id='left'>left</div>
    <div id='center'>center</div>
    <div id='right'>right</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way, without using calc()

```
.container {
    position: relative;
}

.left, .right {
    width: 50%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.left {
    float: left;
    padding-right: 50px;
}

.right {
    float: right; 
    padding-left: 50px;
}

.inner {
    background: red;
    height: 500px;
}

.center {
    background: gray;
    height: 500px;
    width: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

html

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="left"><div class="inner">Left</div></div>
    <div class="right"><div class="inner">Right</div></div>
    <div class="center">Center</div>
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/usb9sbje/3/